# SQL query for datetime

Tags: c#, sql

```
string date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(day - 1).ToShortDateString().ToString();
string count = "select count(*) from Appointment_Info where  APPT_Dt=\'" +
               Convert.ToDateTime(date) + "\'  ";
SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(count, cn);
int appoinments = Convert.ToInt16( cc.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

above query does not work plese see and tell is their any problems?

Comment: Use a parameter, it's really better than formatting dates...

Comment: @sikender: I suppose that you meant to say `You need to specify what kind of error you get`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is such SQL instead:

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(day - 1).Date;
DateTime dtTo = past.AddDays(1);
string strSQL = "Select Count(*) From Appointment_Info Where  APPT_Dt Between @from And @to";
int appoinments = 0;
using (SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cn))
{
    cc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", dtFrom);
    cc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dtTo);
    appoinments = Int32.Parse(cc.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
```

Problem is you don't need **exact** date as it won't give you anything, you rather need **range** of dates meaning anything between the past date and day after it.

The above code also give better practice of using parameters and properly disposing the Command object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem:

```
    string date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(day - 1).ToShortDateString().ToString();
    string count = "select count(*) from Appointment_Info where  convert(int,convert(varchar, APPT_Dt,112))=convert(int,convert(varchar, @date,112)) ";

    SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(count, cn);
    cc.parameters.AddWithValue("@date",date);
    int appoinments = Convert.ToInt16( cc.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(day - 1);
SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Appointment_Info WHERE APPT_Dt=@dt", cn);
cc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
```